# Can not authorise user in Facebook JS SDK : "This authorization code has been used." or how to get new authorisation token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I am trying to use Facebook to authenticate users. It works ok except for Ajax calls. Most of the times it just send old token and I get :

```
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

So what I tried doing is wrapping every ajax call with

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            return  fn();
            ...
```

this did not worked so I've added : true as parameter to getLoginStatus to prevent caching :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('connected');
            fn();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            console.log('not_authorized);
        } else {
            console.log('not_logged_in');
        }
    },true);
```

Great! Except it is terribly slow. Am I doing something wrong? Can I get new token after each action so I do not need to wait before the next one?

Thanks
W

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's what Facebook says:

"New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes. 
We will only allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10 minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be short lived and single use". For more information, check out our Authentication documentation.

The way around this is to use the extending your access token api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: I understand that. But is there an option to get new code automatically? Wouldn't this make JS SDK unusable for frequent ajax calls if I need to get new token before each call? Is there a solution for that except creating user on server side and putting it into session?

Comment: Ahh, yes : ) - You have to extend your access tokens

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: Can you link to the source of facebook answer?

Comment: My answer is now 4 years old : P